# Excel: How to pick a sheet based on cell values

Tags: excel-formula

I've got an excel workbook with a number of sheets calculating statistics and a single summary sheet.

On the summary sheet I'd like it to name other sheets that fit certain criteria. So, for example: Let's say the sheets are all named after football teams and in each one there is a cell that calculates "Average Points Per Game". How could I have a cell on the summary sheet pick the team with the highest Average Points Per Game (APPG) and name it as well as its APPG?

Thank you in advance. I've used Excel quite a bit but only for very simple stuff - this is my first time working across multiple sheets in this way.

Comment: Based on your description that would mean you have a finite number of sheets.  Basically the number of teams in the league/division would be the number of sheets.  One approach would be on your summary sheet or on a another work sheet to make a column with individually linked cells to the APPG for each Team worksheet.  Adjacent to the cell in the next column place the worksheet name that you linked to.  do this manually for each row.  When you are done you will have a column of APPG and a Column of sheet names were the came from.

Comment: After that simply find the MAX(APPG column), then do a VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH based on the MAX(APPG) value and return the value that corresponds from the team name column.  The better question is what are you going to do if there is more than one team that has the maximum value?

Comment: You may also want to look into something called 3D MAX.  Its not an excel function, but try a google search for that and Excel and see what comes up for description and that may be partially what you are looking for.

Comment: This will pull the sheet name of a cell on any other sheet except the one you are on.  you just need to change the `Sheet1!A1` to the cell address on another sheet.  This way if you ever rename your sheet in the future your formulas would update the list of names for you.  `=MID(CELL("address",Sheet1!A1),FIND("]",CELL("address",Sheet1!A1))+1,FIND("!",CELL("address",Sheet1!A1))-FIND("]",CELL("address",Sheet1!A1))-1)`